# httpd.conf is cached and no editing is succesful

Tags: apache2, cache, webserver, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I am going to use the WSL system on Windows10 to create a website.
The distro is Ubuntu.

I put httpd.conf in /etc/apache2/conf-available

where there are these two lines (line 40):

```
Define SRVROOT "/etc/apache2"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"
```

When I try to start Apache it says that an error is found:

```
ServerRoot must be a valid directory (line 40)
```

The fact is that I can edit the file, or even comment those two lines, or remove the httpd.conf file

but the error is issued every time I try to start Apache.

I suspect that files are cached.

How to avoid this kind of caching or solve the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work on Windows, but on Linux that conf available directory would be SIM linked from the conf enabled directory. It's possible on Windows the files get copied rather than SIM linked cuz I don't think Windows supports SIM links. In any case it might be worth checking the conf enabled directory and see what's there.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Thanks, it was a mistake of mine, in fact I created the file in the conf-enabled folder, then I forgot it, and eventually created another one in conf-available.

Comment: Caching does not apply if you restart the server. The only possible conclusion is that it's the wrong file. The one being read is elsewhere.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you indicate in the comments that you solved the problem without getting an answer.